# Inspect dynamic drop down menu

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate drop down which is populated dynamically.

When I try to inspect it; it gets closed.

How to interact with this kind of dynamic drop down to find its elements and click one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working as below

1. driver.getPageSource() to fetch all the page elements when drop down is opened post clicking on element
2. note put break point after selenium script which does click on dynamic drop down & later fetches pagesource immediately

   - click action
   - getPageSource action to save into temp string
   - break point to look into string
3. copy this and paste into https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer > Beautify/Format
4. Goto full screen mode, clicking inside the window and search for drop down option name https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer#
5. Also keep the console open to check the element which gets created dynamically post clicking drop down element. Now search this in xml tree.
6. This way one can locate element for this kind of unique constraints.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the dropdown, click Inspect Element, and find it in the devtools.
2. Left-click on the dropdown to open it.
3. Right-click on an option in the open dropdown but *do NOT click Inspect Element*.
4. Press Escape to close the context menu.

Now you can scroll through the HTML and find the options in the devtools.

Comment: Right click on drop down closes it

Comment: Post a link to the page.

Comment: It's under development so can't share yet

Comment: Find another public page that has the same behavior and post it.